# Find elements which appear together in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists in python

```
results = [[1,2],[2,1],[3,0],[0,3],[3,4],[2,5]]
```

I want an efficient solution to get the elements which appear together from list of lists.

I want the output to be like:

```
result = [[1,2,5],[3,0,4]]
```

The order doesn't matter I am only looking for a solution which is efficient preferably without a ton of loops. Thanks

Comment: Then because of ```[3,1]``` all the elements should be together ```[[1,2,3,0,4,5]]``` because of ```[3,1]``` link it will also include all the rest of elements in the same list.

Comment: DO you want a pure python solution or another library is OK?

Comment: yeah its ok as long as its efficient. My main project also uses numpy so I wonder if I should add that as one of questions tags as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say another approach is OK. I have a solution with `networkx` as popular with the name [`networkx.connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components):

```
import networkx as nx
results = [[1,2],[2,1],[3,0],[0,3],[3,4],[2,5]]
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from(results)
print([list(c) for c in nx.connected_components(graph)])
# [[1, 2, 5], [0, 3, 4]]
```